# Can we pass a Url path and a file name to FileOutputStream in java

Tags: java

Sir I am new in java i Want to write a file on URL path is there is any possible way to write a file on URL path give me some tips

Comment: refer to some good java file handling tutorial

Comment: It lacks information.

Comment: What protocol do you want to use to transfer the data? FileOutputStream won't work, you have to use a way that uses a specific protocol (HTTP PUT, FTP etc.)

Comment: Do you mean file name by "file"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can not pass URL path and FileName both as a parameter to FileOutputStream.

However you can write a to a file by reading from a specified URL using the below code:

```
 try{    
            URL url = new URL("http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html");
            String path = "D://StackOverflow/";
            InputStream ins = url.openStream();
            OutputStream ous = new FileOutputStream(path);
            final byte[] b = new byte[2048];
            int length;

                while ((length = ins.read(b)) != -1) {
                       ous.write(b, 0, length);
                 }

                   ins.close();
                   ous.close();
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And could you please explain what you are actually trying to achieve by passing URL and fileName to FileOutPutStream?

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File(url.getPath());
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

This actually works for simple cases, like for `file:/path/to/abc` (which is actually a malformed file URL since it's missing //) or `file:///path/to/abc` (the correct file URL syntax.) However, this fails to work when the path contains URL-unsafe characters, such as `file:///c:/Documents%20and%20Settings/...`, because `"%20"` ends up in file name, which is wrong.

We've been told that java.net.URI is added in JDK1.5 to replace the broken URL class, so why don't we try that?

```
File file = new File(url.toURI());
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

This nicely converts %20 to a space (and all the other escaped characters.) The problem solved? Nope. URI is very draconian, and it fails to handle URLs like `file:///c:/Documents and Settings/`. This URL is broken as far as RFCs are concerned, but the reality is that java.net.URL accepts it happily, so you often end up seeing this. I'm sure many have done `new URL("file://"+fileName);` — those are the code that creates this URL.

So the current version I have is to combine both:

```
    File file;
    try {
      file = new File(url.toURI());
    } catch(URISyntaxException e) {
      file = new File(url.getPath());
    }
   FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

yeap, it should be possible - you can use constructor `new FileOutputStream(new File(new URI()))`. Read more about java.net.URI class.